# Replacing a URL Directory Name Using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

My current website is:

```
example.com/Hand_Soap/
```

There are also many pages like:

```
example.com/Hand_Soap/Blue

example.com/Hand_Soap/Green
```

etc

How do I make a 301 redirect to:

```
example.com/Hand_Wash/

example.com/Hand_Wash/Blue

example.com/Hand_Wash/Green
```

etc

I have looked at several posts on this site, but none seem to work for me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the WP direction plugin. Works well!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
   redirect 301 /Hand_Soap/ http://example.com/Hand_Wash/
   redirect 301 /Hand_Soap/Blue http://example.com/Hand_Wash/Blue
   redirect 301 /Hand_Soap/Green http://example.com/Hand_Wash/Green
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking more for a automatic solutions (there are thousands of pages). In the end I used the WP direction plugin. Works well!